# How to set brakpoint in Visual Studio Code when an object changes?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, fastapi, breakpoints

I'm working on a Python/FastAPI application where I have this endpoint :

```
from fastapi import Request
@router_phase.get("/hello", response_class=HTMLResponse)
def hello(
    request: Request,
):
    ...
```

`request` has an attribute `user` which tracks user information, which has an attribute, ip_address (for example)
which is not `None`.

Somewhere the application hit an Exception, and Visual Studio Code arrives at following exception handler

```
@app.exception_handler(500)
def custom_500_handler(
    request: Request,
    error: Exception,
):
    ...
```

Now `request` still has an attribute `user`, which is the same as in `hello` (because I run `id(request.user)`, but `request.user.ip_address` is `None` now.

The question is : Is it possible to set a breakpoint so that debugger stops where `ip_address` changes.

Comment: set breakpoints on known locations along the path of execution of request, find the breakpoint not hit, use previous breakpoint and single step to find the line with the problem

Comment: @rioV8 That depends on `single stepping`. `Is there no way to set a breakpoint so that debugger stops where ip_address changes.`

Comment: maybe `ip_address` changes because the corruption executes the wrong code and you still don't know what is causing that. What is the problem of using a few single steps. If the debugger supports data breakpoints you can see it in the breakpoint view

Comment: Microsoft uses the term "data breakpoint" for that feature; have you seen https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_data-breakpoints ?

Comment: @MatsLindh `If a debugger supports data breakpoints ...` How can I know if Python debugger supports data breakpoints ?

Comment: If what you want is an automatic interrupt when a variable changes, I opened [an issue in Github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/21455) for you.